# find names of classes with the highest enrollement

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I have the following relation in database

```
ENROLLMENT (snum: int, cname:varchar(100))
```

where snum is the student id and cname is the course name

and I want to find the name(s) of the class(s) with the most students enrolled.

Comment: Please show your schema, sample data, expected output and what you have tried

Comment: Poor table design. Don't store class name for each student. Store class id instead, and have the name in the classes table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple solutions. One solution is usage of `SELECT TOP 1` :

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    cname, count(*) as NumberOfStudents
FROM ENROLLMENT
GROUP BY cname
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

Comment: Will only return 1 row, even if it's a tie.

Comment: @jarlh If multiple rows are required it is simple enough to change to `TOP 1 WITH TIES`....

Comment: @GarethD, thanks, I didn't know SQL Server had that!

Answer (score 2):

Use a common table expression (cte):

```
with cte as
(
  select cname, count(*) as cnt
  from ENROLLMENT
  group by cname
)
select cname
from cte
where cnt = (select max(cnt) from cte)
```

Comment: OK, but in case of a tie, you will get multiple rows.

Comment: @SQLOTL, the cte will only return each sid once (thanks to the group by). In case of a tie, both sids will be returned.

Comment: Sorry @jarlh your query is wrong  - she is not interested in the SIDs, she wants to know which classes have the most students! so your cte should not group by sid, rather it should group by cname !

Comment: @SQLOTL, I noticed that a few seconds before you did. See my already updated answer.

Comment: I see it, now it's correct! Well, and in case of a tie, @sarahM needs to decide what she wants. If she wants only ONE result, then the other solution with `SELECT TOP 1` would be preferred.

Comment: @SQLOTL, I suppose "I want to find the name(s) of the class(s) with the most students enrolled" means OP wants both names in case of a tie.

Comment: Interestingly SQL Server appears to convert this query to a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` query within the compilation process, meaning when run against a single table both queries are essentially identical. On more complex queries the optimiser was not able to do this meaning that this method became slower than `TOP` because the complex query was having to be executed twice.

Comment: To further throw a spanner in the works on a much simpler query with only a couple of joins SQL Server is still able to convert this to a query using `TOP`, however it is also able to better use parallelism to attain faster execution, so in this test this method was faster than using `TOP 1 WITH TIES`. Ultimately (as always) which is the most efficient method will depend, but I would be inclined to go for the `TOP 1 WITH TIES` method because it is less verbose, and has a better chance of avoiding duplicate table reads.

Comment: Here is a demo of the [simple query with the same optimisation](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/23f5d/3), and the [Complex query that is slower](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/23f5d/2), I was unable to quickly reproduce with test data the behaviour that saw this method outperform `TOP 1` so I haven't set up a link for that.

Comment: @GarethD, wow, you're really the benchmark master!!! (I don't even know SQL Server, so don't expect any useful info from me.)

Comment: It's a slow day at work, and I was curious as to how each method would perform, and which would be preferable. Having found that in different circumstances each method would perform differently, I figured I may as well share that, even if nobody cares, otherwise I would have felt like the last 10 minutes were a waste of time...

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for your highly interesting explanations and tests! I also wondered which version would perform better. In any way, a version which needs only one single pass is clearly better off. A 3rd approach would possibly be with a `partition by` but I didn't think it through. And BTW, the optimizer in SQL Server is indeed fantastic, I often find that it is almost doing wonders!